# Solving equations involving both algebra, trigonometry (and possible use of inequalities)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are solutions $a\tan\theta+ b\sec\theta = c$
>   then show that:
>
> $\tan(\alpha+\beta)= \dfrac{2ac}{a^2-c^2}$

This is the first time I am attempting such a question so I am confused. Nevertheless, I gave it a try:

$\dfrac{a\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}+\dfrac{b}{\cos\theta}=c
$

$\implies a\sin\theta -c\cos\theta= -b$

Now, 
$-\sqrt{a^2+c^2}\le a\sin\theta -c\cos\theta\le\sqrt{a^2+c^2}$

or,

$-\sqrt{a^2+c^2}\le -b\le\sqrt{a^2+c^2}$

I don't know how to proceed from here. Also, is this a valid approach to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have $$\tan^2 (\theta) + 1 = \sec^2 (\theta)$$
From
$$a \tan \theta + b \sec \theta = c$$
we have $$b\sec \theta = c-a \tan \theta$$

squaring both sides,

$$b^2\sec^2 (\theta)=(c-a\tan\theta)^2$$

$$b^2(\tan^2(\theta)+1)=c^2-2ac\tan\theta+a^2 \tan^2\theta$$

$$(a^2-b^2)\tan^2 (\theta)-2ac\tan \theta + (c^2-b^2) = 0$$

View this as a quadratic equation in $\tan \theta$.

We have $$\tan \alpha + \tan \beta = \frac{2ac}{a^2-b^2}$$

and

$$\tan \alpha \tan \beta = \frac{c^2-b^2}{a^2-b^2}.$$
 Note that 
$$\tan( \alpha + \beta) = \frac{\tan \alpha + \tan \beta}{1 - \tan \alpha \tan \beta}$$

Hence $$\tan (\alpha + \beta) = \frac{\frac{2ac}{a^2-b^2}}{1-\frac{c^2-b^2}{a^2-b^2}} =\frac{2ac}{a^2-c^2}$$

Comment: Was this solution intuitive to you or have you solved such problems before?

Comment: It is intuitive to me that I should view it as a quadratic equation and I am familiar with the trigonometric identitites.